# Upgrading Apache Solr 6.x to 7.x Tokenizer and Criteria multiple values

Tags: java, spring-boot, solr

We are upgrading the lucene apache from solr 6.x to solr 7.x version, After upgrading we have not faced much issue related to query or indexing. (Using SolrTemplate of spring-data-solr-2.1.17.RELEASE.jar)

But one scenario is failing (Solr Result not found) where we are passing a list of string into the Criteria

Code:

```
 new Criteria("status").in(someList); // someList is "ACTIVE" and "Available"
```

While debugging Criteria shows :

> AND status($equals:ACTIVE$equals:Available)

Schema:

```
<field name="status" type="my_custome_field" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
........
<fieldType name="my_custome_field" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="true" sortMissingLast="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
       <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
       <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

We are getting result in 6.x and not in 7.x version. Please let me know any changes required here.

**Edit:**

As suggested by @MatsLindh, Have added the `q.op` sorlconfig.xml

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <int name="rows">10</int>
      <str name="df">text</str>
      <str name="q.op">OR</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Still getting no result found.

Comment: Is the query generated without any spaces between the two terms? (check the Solr log to see exactly what's being sent to Solr)

Comment: I could see the 'SolrQuery' prepared like : q=status:(ACTIVE+Available)

Comment: That seems correct. Initial guess is that the default `q.op` has changed to `AND` instead of `OR`. Check the active `solrconfig.xml` for the current configuration, and test supplying it manually in the URL (`q.op=OR`) to see if you get results back (directly to Solr instead of going through Spring)

Comment: @MatsLindh Both solr version have the default generated solrconfig.xml (I could not locate the "q.op") and I have passed manually in solr : q={!q.op=OR}status:(ACTIVE%20Available) and still not able to get results.

Comment: If the query parser is not the lucene query parser by default (for example if it's the edismax handler), localparams may not be expanded by default. Try to append it as an explicit parameter: `&q.op=OR`. You can also append `debug=all` to get information about exactly what the query Solr sees is, and how it's being parsed.

Comment: @MatsLindh Here what i have found after adding debug, In 7.x query is "parsedquery_toString":"status:active available", in 6.x it is "parsedquery_toString":"status:active status:available" and "QParser":"LuceneQParser" Please suggest what can do now?

Comment: is there any defType or a different qparser for the 7.x query? For debugging you can also change the `luceneMatchVersion` to the same version as you're using of 6.x - that will tell you if anything has changed in a non-backwards compatible manner for the parser in question.

Comment: @MatsLindh , Please check this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-10310, after 6.6 it seems they have made SolrQueryParser.DEFAULT_SPLIT_ON_WHITESPACE as false and i was using 6.5 where it was true.

Comment: Correct; i didn't think that it'd affect the Lucene syntax as shown above, but that might have been wrong. Did you test with `sow=true` in the URL to see if you got the old behavior back?

Comment: @MatsLindh Finally , It worked when i gave `sow=true` in solrconfig. Hope it will not have any other impacts.